# How to show loader while exporting chart as Image in amCharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

Clicking on the export button sometime takes too much time. Clicking multiple times leads to a popup where it ask permission to allow multiple file download. When I don't allow multiple download I am not able to download any chart. Is it possible  to show a loader while some downloading happening at background? or is there some other solution for this ?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Export plugin's [`beforeCapture`](https://github.com/amcharts/export#events) event handler to temporarily disable the export menu so that it can't be clicked twice.

To do that, simply use `crateMenu()` call with one empty menu item.

```
"export": {
  "enabled": true,
  "beforeCapture": function() {
    this.createMenu( [{
      "class": "export-main disabled"
    }] );
  }
}
```

Please note the `class` setting for the item. The "export-main" part will ensure that the button looks like the default export button. I also added the "disabled" part. We can use that to override default style for such disabled element with custom CSS. I.e.:

```
.amcharts-export-menu .export-main.disabled > a {
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

I provided a very simple CSS override here. You may replace it with much sophisticated style, like animated gif in it, or something else. Up to you.

We don't need to reset back the menu, since Export plugin will do that for us when exporting is done.

Here's a complete working demo:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "marginRight": 70,
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 3025,
    "color": "#FF0F00"
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "color": "#FF6600"
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809,
    "color": "#FF9E01"
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322,
    "color": "#FCD202"
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122,
    "color": "#F8FF01"
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114,
    "color": "#B0DE09"
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984,
    "color": "#04D215"
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711,
    "color": "#0D8ECF"
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665,
    "color": "#0D52D1"
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580,
    "color": "#2A0CD0"
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443,
    "color": "#8A0CCF"
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441,
    "color": "#CD0D74"
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Visitors from country"
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "labelRotation": 45
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "beforeCapture": function() {
      this.createMenu( [{
        "class": "export-main disabled"
      }] );
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.amcharts-export-menu .export-main.disabled > a {
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help ! This is what I was looking for. It's working perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

There is J query plugin 'fileDownload'. Here is the link they have working demo.

http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

Comment: It's not clear how this answer relates to the question, or how it can be useful.

Comment: @ranjan Thank you for the help, but it was not useful for the required problem.